# Comparing two definitions of pullback differential form

Tags: differential-geometry

### Some preliminary definitions

Let $ M $ be a smooth manifold.

#### Differential forms as sections of $ \bigwedge^k\mathrm T^*M\to M $

Consider the vector bundle $ \bigwedge^k\mathrm T^*M\to M $, where of course
$$
\bigwedge\nolimits^k\mathrm T^*M = \coprod_{p\in M}\bigwedge\nolimits^k\mathrm T_p^*M
$$
and the map $ \bigwedge^k\mathrm T^*M\to M $ is the obvious projection.

In differential geometry textbooks, given an open set $ U\subset M $, a *differential form* on $ U $ is defined as a smooth section $ \omega\colon U\to \bigwedge^k\mathrm T^*M $ of such a bundle, i.e. as a map $ \omega\colon U\to \bigwedge\nolimits^k\mathrm T^*M $ such that
$$
\omega_p\in \bigwedge\nolimits^k\mathrm T_p^*M
$$
for every $ p\in M $.

#### Differential forms as sections of $ \left(\bigwedge^k\mathrm TM\right)^*\to M $

On the other hand, one can consider the bundle $ \left(\bigwedge^k\mathrm TM\right)^*\to M $ where
$$
\left(\bigwedge\nolimits^k\mathrm TM\right)^* = \coprod_{p\in M}\left(\bigwedge\nolimits^k \mathrm T_pM\right)^*
$$
with the obvious projection mapping.

A *differential form* on $ U $ can now be defined as a section of this bundle, i.e. as a smooth map $ \omega\colon U\to \left(\bigwedge^k\mathrm TM\right)^* $ such that
$$
\omega_p\colon \bigwedge\nolimits^k \mathrm T_pM\to \mathbb R
$$
is $ \mathbb R $-linear.

#### The two definitions coincide

It's well known from linear algebra that there is a perfect pairing
$$
\langle{{-},{-}}\rangle\colon \bigwedge\nolimits^k \mathrm T_p^*M\times \bigwedge\nolimits^k \mathrm T_pM\to \mathbb R
$$
such that
$$
\left\langle\mathrm dx^{i_1}\rvert_p\wedge\dots \wedge\mathrm dx^{i_k}\rvert_p,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j_1}}\Biggr\rvert_p\wedge\dots\wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j_k}}\Biggr\rvert_p\right\rangle = \delta_{i_1,\dots,i_k}^{j_1,\dots,j_k}
$$
for any choice of coordinates $ x^1,\dots,x^n $ on $ \mathrm T_pM $.

So, every differential form in-the-first-sense $ \omega\colon U\to \bigwedge^k\mathrm T^*M $ can be thought as a differential form in-the-second-sense $ \tilde\omega\colon U\to \left(\bigwedge^k\mathrm TM\right)^* $ by
$$
\tilde\omega_p = \langle{\omega_p,{-}}\rangle\colon \bigwedge\nolimits^k\mathrm T_pM\to \mathbb R
$$
for every $ p\in M $. And viceversa, every differential form in-the-second-sense $ \omega\colon U\to \left(\bigwedge^k\mathrm TM\right)^* $ can be thought as a differential form $ \tilde\omega \colon U\to \bigwedge^k \mathrm T^*M $ by exploiting the isomorphism between the exterior power of the dual and the dual of the exterior power.

### The question. I.e., two definitions of the pullback form

Introduce another smooth manifold $ N $ and a smooth mapping $ F\colon M\to N $.

#### Pullback of differential forms: first case

Given a differential form in-the-first-sense $ \eta\colon V\to \bigwedge^l\mathrm T^*N $ defined on some $ V\subset N $ open, one can defined another differential form $ F^*\eta\colon F^{-1}(V)\to \bigwedge^l\mathrm T^*M $ in-the-first-sense on $ F^{-1}(V)\subset M $, called the *pullback* of $ \eta $ by $ F $, in the following way.

First, consider the differential of $ F $, i.e. the map $ \mathrm T_pF\colon \mathrm T_pM\to \mathrm T_{F(p)}N $. Then take its transpose $ \mathrm T_p^*F\colon \mathrm T_{F(p)}^*N\to \mathrm T_p^*M $. Then take its $ l $th exterior power $ \bigwedge^l\mathrm T_p^*F\colon \bigwedge^l\mathrm T_{F(p)}^*N\to \bigwedge^l\mathrm T_p^*M $.

At this point we're ready to define $ F^*\eta $: it's just
$$
(F^*\eta)_p = \left(\bigwedge\nolimits^l\mathrm T_p^*F\right)(\eta_{F(p)})
$$
for every $ p\in F^{-1}(V) $.

#### Pullback of differential forms: second case

Starting from the second definition of differential form given in this long post, one can come up with a different definition of pullback form.

Take a differential form in-the-second-sense $ \eta\colon V\to \left(\bigwedge^l\mathrm TN\right)^* $ on an open set $ V\subset N $. Consider differential $ \mathrm T_pF\colon \mathrm T_pM\to \mathrm T_{F(P)}N $ and its exterior power $ \bigwedge^l\mathrm T_pF\colon \bigwedge^l\mathrm T_pM\to \bigwedge^l\mathrm T_{F(p)}N $.

It's clear now that to define some differential form $ F^*\eta\colon F^{-1}(V)\to \left(\bigwedge^l\mathrm TM\right)^* $ is sufficient to put
$$
(F^*\eta)_p = \eta_{F(p)}\circ \bigwedge\nolimits^l\mathrm T_pF
$$
for every $ p\in F^{-1}(V) $.

#### Do these two constructions lead to the same thing?

Now, as we learnt above a differential form in-the-first-sense leads to a differential form in-the-second-sense.

I was wondering if

1. starting from a differential form in-the-first-sense;
2. taking its pullback "in-the-first-sense";
3. and then considering the differential forms in-the-second-sense that results from the previous construction;

will give the same result of

1. starting from a differential form in-the-first-sense;
2. considering the differential forms in-the-second-sense that results from the previous construction;
3. taking its pullback "in-the-second-sense".

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with manifolds or differential forms. You're just asking to compare the (multi)linear algebra of the pullback under $T\colon V\to W$, in the first case looking at $T^*\colon\bigwedge^l W^*\to\bigwedge^l V^*$ and in the second case looking at $T^*\colon (\bigwedge^l W)^*\to (\bigwedge^l V)^*$. What is the issue? Evaluating the output of the first on $(v_1,\dots,v_l)$ is the same as evaluating the second on $v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_l$.

Comment: Oh, I see. This is just the naturality
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\bigwedge^l T_p^*M @<{\cong}<< \left(\bigwedge^l T_pM\right)^*\\
@A{\bigwedge^l T_p^*F}AA @AA{\left(\bigwedge^l T_pF\right)^*}A\\
\bigwedge^l T_{F(p)}^*N @<{\cong}<< \left(\bigwedge^l T_{F(p)}N\right)^*
\end{CD}
$$
which is not an entirely trivial fact tho.

Comment: Putting manifolds and tangent spaces back in obscures it. I still don’t see the issue with the iso $\bigwedge^l V^* \cong \left(\bigwedge^l V\right){}^*$.

Comment: Oh, but I do agree with you indeed. It was just faster to write that diagram above copy-pasting all along my previous notation :)